# Adding values to python dataframe based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lambda

(Python) I'm trying to fill a column based off of information in another column. Many of the cells in  the Service column are NaN.. IF the Service is NaN, I want to fill the Service cell with the Service name from a row with the same first/last name, IF that row doesnt have NaN in the service column.

See Carl below, for example. How do i fill Carl's NaN "Service" columns with "Endocrinology", based off of matching first/last name row containing the identical first/last name, and repeat for all? And If there is no Service name for that person (John), leave it as NAN?

```
df=[['P, Carl', 'NaN'],
['P, Carl', 'Endocrinology'],
['P, Carl', 'NaN'],
['W, Kate', 'Neurology'],
['W, Kate', 'NaN'],
['V, John', 'NaN']]
```

I tried using np.where and filtering the data. i can't quite wrap my head around a for loop or lambda

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I couldve created the df as Marcelo did in their response

Answer (score 1):

I modified your data frame so that it actually contains `NaN` instead of the **string** `NaN`:

```
data = [['P, Carl', np.nan],
['P, Carl', 'Endocrinology'],
['P, Carl', np.nan],
['W, Kate', 'Neurology'],
['W, Kate', np.nan],
['V, John', np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Service'])
```

Now we can get use `groupby`, `ffill`, `bfill` and `apply` to get the desired result:

```
df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Our `df` now looks like this:

```
      Name        Service
0  P, Carl  Endocrinology
1  P, Carl  Endocrinology
2  P, Carl  Endocrinology
3  W, Kate      Neurology
4  W, Kate      Neurology
5  V, John            NaN
```

Comment: You're welcome, @keeptrying. It would be appreciated if you upvote/accept this answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [['P, Carl', np.nan],
        ['P, Carl', 'Endocrinology'],
        ['P, Carl', np.nan],
        ['W, Kate', 'Neurology'],
        ['W, Kate', np.nan],
        ['V, John', np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Service'])
"""print(df)
      Name        Service
0  P, Carl            NaN
1  P, Carl  Endocrinology
2  P, Carl            NaN
3  W, Kate      Neurology
4  W, Kate            NaN
5  V, John            NaN"""
def fill_service(df):
    df['Service'] = df.groupby('Name')['Service'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
    return df

df = fill_service(df.copy())  
"""print(df)
      Name        Service
0  P, Carl  Endocrinology
1  P, Carl  Endocrinology
2  P, Carl  Endocrinology
3  W, Kate      Neurology
4  W, Kate      Neurology
5  V, John            NaN
"""
```